# html request via asp.net mvc site

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

customer use http://aaa.com/uploads/bb/index.html to request my ASP.NET MVC site. I want to make sure the customer has enough permission to access the site, so I need catch the request and deal with it. I'm using `IHttpModule` to do that.

```
public class myHttpModule : IHttpModule {
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

        Uri url = application.Context.Request.Url;
        string path = url.AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
```

the question is when second time use the same url to request the website, the `HttpModule` can't catch the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer!It's about the http cache. 
I write code as below and the problem was killed:

```
public class myHttpModule : IHttpModule {
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
}

void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

    Uri url = application.Context.Request.Url;
    string path = url.AbsoluteUri;
    **app.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);**
}
```

}